# C# Get All Diagonals Jagged Array

Tags: c#, algorithm, array, jagged-array

How can I improve this?

The idea is to store every left to right diagonals in a list

Not looking for a more efficient algorithm instead something readable, LINQ perhaps?

**input:**

**3**, **1**
**2**, **5**, **7**
**1**, **5**, **8**, **3**, 1, 4
6, **8**, **7**, **1**
4
**6**
6, **2**, 5

**output:**

```
1, 7, 3,
3, 5, 8, 1,
7, 3,
5, 8, 1,
2, 5, 7,
8, 1,
5, 7,
1, 8,
6, 2,
```

--

```
    var arr = new[]
{
    new[]{3,1},
    new[]{2,5,7},
    new[]{1,5,8,3,1,4},
    new[]{6,8,7,1},
    new[]{4},
    new[]{6},
    new[]{6,2,5}
};

GetAllDiagonals(arr);
Console.ReadKey();

static void GetAllDiagonals(int[][] array)
{
    var e = new List<List<int>>();

    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = array[i].Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            var n = i;
            var x = j;
            var next = i + 1 <= array.Length - 1 && j < array[n + 1].Length - 1;
            var index = 0;
            if (next)
            {
                e.Add(new List<int>());
                index = e.Count - 1;
            }

            while (next)
            {
                e[index].Add(array[n][x]);
                next = n + 1 <= array.Length - 1 && x < array[n + 1].Length - 1;
                n++; x++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < e.Count; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < e[i].Count; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(e[i][j] + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the expected output is correct? Like why does it include `5 8 1` it's not diagonal? According to my understand the result should include these: `1 8`, `2 5 7`, `3 5 8 1` and `1 7 3`. Or please define what do you mean by diagonal

Comment: This conditional `j <= e[i].Count - 1` really should be `j < e[i].Count`.

Comment: Yes @PeterCsala my initial purpose was to store only the one mentioned however it proved more difficult

Comment: @Laycoonz On the contrary that simplifies design. You have to start the diagonal searching only from the first column or from the first row. Tomorrow I will leave a post with the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Apologise for my poor visualisation. I've used Excel to draw the bellow diagrams.*

---

#### Finding the diagonal step-by-step

Let's play a little bit with your example

[image: the original matrix]

As you have said it in your question you want to find all left to right diagonals.

I've used the following **informal** definition for the left to right diagonal:

- A descending line which starts either from the left or from the top side of the matrix until there is a number in the way of it
- The minimum length of the line is two

I haven't read any requirements regarding the ordering so, lets suppose you want to find them from left to right

[image: first]
[image: second]
[image: third]
[image: fourth]
[image: fifth]

#### Algorithm

I hope you have noticed the following part (highlighted with bold) in my informal definition:

> A descending line which starts either **from the left** or **from the top** side of the matrix until there is a number in the way of it

That means you have to have two top level iterations

- On the 1st column from bottom to the top
- On the 1st row from left to right

[image: bottom to top] [image: left to right]

To find a diagonal you need the following steps:

1. Increment both column and row indices
2. Check whether there is a number under the new indices

   1. If yes repeat step 1 and 2
   2. If not then check line's length

      1. If it is greater than one then you have found a diagonal
      2. If it is 1 then you continue the iteration on the top-level

#### Implementation

Now let's see how do we implement the above algorithm.
Let's start with the diagonals search which starts from left

```
static List<List<int>> FindDiagonalsWhichStartsFromLeft(int[][] input)
{
    var diagonals = new List<List<int>>();
    //Bottom top iteration on first column
    for (int row = input.Length - 1; row > 0; row--)
    {
        int rowIndex = row, columnIndex = 0;
        var diagonal = new List<int>()
        {
            input[rowIndex][columnIndex]
        };

        //#2.1 If yes repeat step 1 and 2
        while (true)
        {
            //#1 Increment both column and row indices
            rowIndex++; columnIndex++;

            //#2 Check whether there is a number under the new indices
            if (rowIndex >= input.Length ||
                columnIndex >= input[rowIndex].Length)
            {
                break;
            }

            diagonal.Add(input[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
        }

        //#2.2.1 If it is greater than one then you have found a diagonal
        if (diagonal.Count > 1)
        {
            diagonals.Add(diagonal);
        }

        //#2.2.2 If it is 1 then you continue the iteration on the top-level
    }

    return diagonals;
}
```

Please note that we have done a reverse loop here from the last row till the 2nd row. We skipped the 1st row because otherwise the main diagonal will be found twice

[image: main diagonal]

Of course you can avoid this duplicate in another way like starting from the 2nd column whenever you are searching for diagonals which is starting from the top. (*Where to put the prevention logic is up to you.*)

Now let's see the other iteration

```
static List<List<int>> FindDiagonalsWhichStartsFromTop(int[][] input)
{
    var diagonals = new List<List<int>>();
    //Left to Right iteration on first row
    for (int column = 0; column < input[0].Length; column++)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0, columnIndex = column;
        var diagonal = new List<int>()
    {
        input[rowIndex][columnIndex]
    };

        //#2.1 If yes repeat step 1 and 2
        while (true)
        {
            //#1 Increment both column and row indices
            rowIndex++; columnIndex++;

            //#2 Check whether there is a number under the new indices
            if (rowIndex >= input.Length ||
                columnIndex >= input[rowIndex].Length)
            {
                break;
            }

            diagonal.Add(input[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
        }

        //#2.2.1 If it is greater than one then you have found a diagonal
        if (diagonal.Count > 1)
        {
            diagonals.Add(diagonal);
        }

        //#2.2.2 If it is 1 then you continue the iteration on the top-level
    }

    return diagonals;
}
```

As you can see the only difference here is the outer loop. So, the *"core logic"* is untouched which means we can extract that into its own method

```
static void GetDiagonal(int[][] input, List<int> diagonal, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    //#2.1 If yes repeat step 1 and 2
    while (true)
    {
        //#1 Increment both column and row indices
        rowIndex++; columnIndex++;

        //#2 Check whether there is a number under the new indices
        if (rowIndex >= input.Length ||
            columnIndex >= input[rowIndex].Length)
        {
            break;
        }

        diagonal.Add(input[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
    }
}
```

---

For the sake of completeness let me share with you the full source code (without comments for the sake of brevity)

```
static void Main()
{
    var arr = new[]
    {
        new[]{3,1},
        new[]{2,5,7},
        new[]{1,5,8,3,1,4},
        new[]{6,8,7,1},
        new[]{4},
        new[]{6},
        new[]{6,2,5}
    };
    FindAndPrintDiagonals(arr);
}

static void FindAndPrintDiagonals(int[][] input)
{
    var diagonalsFromLeft = FindDiagonalsWhichStartsFromLeft(input);
    var diagonalsFromTop = FindDiagonalsWhichStartsFromTop(input);
    foreach (var diagonal in diagonalsFromLeft.Union(diagonalsFromTop))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", diagonal));
    }
}

static List<List<int>> FindDiagonalsWhichStartsFromLeft(int[][] input)
{
    var diagonals = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int row = input.Length - 1; row > 0; row--)
    {
        int rowIndex = row, columnIndex = 0;
        var diagonal = new List<int>()
        {
            input[rowIndex][columnIndex]
        };

        GetDiagonal(input, diagonal, rowIndex, columnIndex);
        if (diagonal.Count > 1)
            diagonals.Add(diagonal);
    }
    return diagonals;
}

static List<List<int>> FindDiagonalsWhichStartsFromTop(int[][] input)
{
    var diagonals = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int column = 0; column < input[0].Length; column++)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0, columnIndex = column;
        var diagonal = new List<int>()
        {
            input[rowIndex][columnIndex]
        };

        GetDiagonal(input, diagonal, rowIndex, columnIndex);
        if (diagonal.Count > 1)
            diagonals.Add(diagonal);
    }
    return diagonals;
}

static void GetDiagonal(int[][] input, List<int> diagonal, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    while (true)
    {
        rowIndex++; columnIndex++;
        if (rowIndex >= input.Length || columnIndex >= input[rowIndex].Length)
            break;
        
        diagonal.Add(input[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
    }
}
```

Here is a working [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ddtUi) link.
You should see the following output on the console:

```
6 2
1 8
2 5 7
3 5 8 1
1 7 3
```

Comment: I take my hat off to you, very good and extensible explanation thank you